# How to express this condition in SharePoint Calculated field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, formula

How to express this condition in SharePoint Calculated field?

A field should have a result of yes or no with below condition:

If ALL the fields value is completed answer should be No, else Yes.

Comment: Do you mean set value to "No" if all list form fields entered by user (when there is no blank field)? Or when list column has value = "completed", set calculated column value to "No".

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula

```
=IF([field1]="completed","No","Yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

1.If you want to set the calculated column value to **No** when all fields have no blank fields, use this formula：

```
=IF(OR(column1="",number1=""),"Yes","No")
```

The running result realizes that when both column1 and number1 have values, **No** is displayed, otherwise **Yes**.
[image]

2.If you want to set the calculated column value to **No** when column has value = "completed", use this formula：

```
=IF([column1]="completed","No","Yes")
```

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Hi @jeanggerr,I am checking the status of this case. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.
If you have any update about this issue, please feel free to post back.

Comment: Did my response answer your question? If I misunderstand something, please let me know! If there is any other assistance i can provide, please feel free to let me know, i will do our best to help you.